# Method that causes infinite calls

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would just like to ask for suggestions and ideas about my current issue , I have a method which is getUserRoles which is fetching the logged-in user roles list.

The problem I have is that there are instances that the getUserGeneralDetails from the getUserRoles that is causing infinity , it is calling the getUserGeneralDetails infinitely and I dont understand why and what causes it.

Maybe somone can enlighten me with some problem with the code snippet I have below. Would be appreciatd, Thanks.

#method

```
  //In this method, we are just fetching the logged-in user roles list.
  public getUserRoles(): Promise<string[]> {

    if (this.authUser === null) {
      this.setAuthUser()
    }
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.userService
      .getUserGeneralDetails(this.authUser.nameid , this.accountId = 0)
        .pipe(catchError((error: any, caught: any) => {
          reject(error);
          return caught;
        }),
          map((res: any) => res.data && res.data.userAccountDto
            .filter(account => account.accountName === res.data.associatedAccount)
            .map(account => account.userRoleDto.roleName)
          )).subscribe((role: string[]) => {
            resolve(role);
          });

    });
  }
```

#code that calls the getUserRoles method

```
this.authService
          .loginWithCredentials(username, password)
          .then((r: any) => {
            localStorage.removeItem("previousUrl");
            if (r.isSuccess) {


              this.authService.getUserRoles().then((userRoles: string[]) => {
                localStorage.setItem("userRoles", JSON.stringify(userRoles));
              })

              
              this.route.navigateByUrl('/');
            }else{                                         
              if(r.errors.length > 0){                
                if(r.errors[0].description.indexOf('not found') !== -1){
                  errMsg = ERR_FORM_MSG.INVALID_LOGIN;
                }
              }
              this.apiErrMsg = errMsg;              
            }
          })
          .catch((e): any => {
            this.apiErrMsg = e.message
              ? e.message
              : errMsg;
          })
          .finally(() => {
            this.hasSubmit = false;
            this.closeLoader();
          });
      }
```

#user details

```
 getUserGeneralDetails(id: number , accountId:number): Observable<any> {
    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('id', id.toString())
      .set('accountId', accountId.toString());
    return this.httpRequestService.get<any>(`${apiBaseUrl}/detail` , params);
  }
```

Comment: it is hard to say where the problem really is, but there is an probable error, in place where you are calling `getUserRoles`. you are not w8ing for it to finish. to w8 for it put `navigateByUrl` inside of `.then` and add `return` before `this.authService....`

Comment: I don't have direct solution to this but generally it looks strange to mixup promises with observables. Why do you create Promise in getUserRoles()? There is no need for it as you already have an observable. I guess that refactoring it to the clean observable approach would resolve the issue but I can't give concrete examples as I don't see the broader picture of the codebase.